# Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client package updated, and now System.Net.Http doesn't exist

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I just updated the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client package in my Xamarin project and now the System.Net.Http namespace doesn't exist anymore. [Here's the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agIXp.png). I was using the MobileServiceClient object to pass through the URL for my Azure backend. What should I do now? I don't want to go back to the previous version if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty explicit.  Do you have a System.Net.Http reference in your app?  If not, add one.

Comment: That's not a helpful answer. The implication from the question is that the package upgrade caused the problem which hints at a NuGet versioning issue which would likely not be fixed by manually adding a reference to System.Net.Http

Answer (score 0):

What is likely to have happened is that the dependency that the package has is for a version of System.Net.Http that is not compatible with your target .net version and the upgrade has removed the old version and not been able to add the new version.

You will need to find the version of System.Net.Http which is a dependency of Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client and find out what version of .Net it targets (the folder is likely to be underneath your packages folder even if the reference is missing).

Then you can decide whether you can target your project at a newer version of .Net or whether you need to downgrade Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.